# ajax result not showing properly in table

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I need to refresh contents in table every 5 seconds. I did this with `ajax` and `setInterval` functions. But the result is not properly displayed.

[image]

This is the result displaying. Here the first row is replaced by last row. I couldn't find the reason.

Here is my code.

**My controller**

```
public function latestReport() {
    $data['incomingCount'] = $this->Home_model->findCount('incoming');
    $data['outgoingCount'] = $this->Home_model->findCount('outgoing');
    $data['droppedCount'] = $this->Home_model->findCount('drop');
    $data['latestReport'] = $this->Home_model->latestReport(10);
    print_r(json_encode($data));
}
```

**Script**

```
function latestReport() {
        $.ajax({
            url : base_url + 'Home/latestReport',
            type : 'POST',
            success:function(data) {
                var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#incomingCount').text(res.incomingCount);
                $('#outgoingCount').text(res.outgoingCount);
                $('#droppedCount').text(res.droppedCount);
                var latestCount = res.latestReport.length;
                for(var i = 0; i < latestCount; i++){
                    var count = parseInt(i) + 1;

                    $('#resNo').text(count);
                    $('#resSource').text(res.latestReport[i]['Source']);
                    $('#resDest').text(res.latestReport[i]['Destination']);
                    $('#resCallerID').text(res.latestReport[i]['CallerID']);
                    $('#CallerTime').text(res.latestReport[i]['CallStartTime']);
                    $('#resStatus').text(res.latestReport[i]['Status']);
                    $('#resAgent').text(res.latestReport[i]['Agent']);
                    $('#resType').text(res.latestReport[i]['Type']);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    var myVar = setInterval(latestReport, 5000);
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="normal-table" id="senderidList">
   <tr>
     <th style="width: 100px">Sl No</th>                                           
     <th style="width: 100px">Source</th>
     <th>Destination</th>
     <th>CallerID</th>
     <th style="width: 150px">Call Start Time</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Agent</th>
     <th>Type</th>                                    
   </tr>
   <?php if( isset($latestReport) && !empty($latestReport)) {
       $i = 1;
       foreach($latestReport as $report) {
   ?>
   <tr>
     <td id="resNo"><?php echo $i++;?></td>
     <td id="resSource"><?php echo $report['Source']?></td>
     <td id="resDest"><?php echo $report['Destination']; ?></td>
     <td id="resCallerID"><?php echo $report['CallerID']?></td>
     <td id="CallerTime"><?php echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s A', strtotime($report['CallStartTime'])); ?></td>
     <td id="resStatus"><?php echo $report['Status']?> </td>
     <td id="resAgent"><?php echo $report['Agent']?> </td>
     <td id="resType"><?php echo $report['Type']?> </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } }
  else {?>  
  <tr><td colspan="4"> No details available</td></tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

I am getting the result from controller properly. But something happened when showing in table.

Comment: Looks like you are using duplicate ids in every row of the table.

Comment: @geeth What you are doing is wrong. You should not use ids for this purpose. In your ajax success handler, add data to your table body. This way new data will gets replaced.

Comment: Ok. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the cells in each row all have the same ID, so you are updating the first row 10 times.

[HTML elements should not have duplicate IDs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127180/6717).

You can do this instead, in PHP:

```
<tr id="row-<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <td class="resNo"><?php echo $i++;?></td>
    ...
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
$('#row-' + count + ' .resNo').text(count);
...
```

Also, there is no need for `parseInt(i)` - just use `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can display your data without giving ID's to 'td' tags in HTML

make your html as follow

```
<table class="normal-table" id="senderidList">
   <thead>
   <tr>
     <th style="width: 100px">Sl No</th>                                           
     <th style="width: 100px">Source</th>
     <th>Destination</th>
     <th>CallerID</th>
     <th style="width: 150px">Call Start Time</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Agent</th>
     <th>Type</th>                                    
   </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody> 

  </tbody>   
</table>
```

Write following code in Success of Your ajax function for appending row 1 by 1

```
$('#senderidList tbody').empty();//clear your data
                var TableBody = '';
                if (data.d.length > 0) {
//following $.each loop will Concate data one by one 
                    $.each(data.d, function (i, latestReport) {
                        TableBody += '<tr><td>' + i + 1 + '<td><td>' + latestReport['Source'] + '<td><td>' + latestReport['Destination'] + '<td><td>' + latestReport['CallerID'] + '<td><td>' + latestReport['CallStartTime'] + '<td><td>' + latestReport['Status'] + '<td><td>' + latestReport['Agent'] + '<td><td>' + latestReport['Type'] + '<td></tr>';
                    });                    
                }
                else
                {
                    TableBody = '<tr><td colspan="4"> No details available</td></tr>';
                }
//append the created html to the table body using append function
                $('#senderidList tbody').append(TableBody);
```

if You want to give Id to every 'td' then you can give in $.each 
`<td id="yourID'+i+'">` for every td in body tag